# How does $p_x$ commute with $p_y$, i.e. $[p_x,p_y]=0$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, momentum, commutator

I know it's a simple and basic question but would someone show me how to evaluate $[\hat{p}_x,\hat{p}_y]$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the definition of the commutator,

$[P_x,P_y] = P_xP_y - P_yP_x$

where,

$P_x = -i\hbar\frac{\partial }{\partial x}$

and,

$P_y = -i\hbar\frac{\partial }{\partial y}$

Therefore,

$P_xP_y \psi = i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(ih\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial y})$
$ = -\hbar^2\frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial x \partial y}$

Similarly,

$P_yP_x\psi = i\hbar\frac{\partial }{\partial y}(ih\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x})$
$ = -\hbar^2\frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial y \partial x}$
$ = -\hbar^2\frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial x \partial y}$

Therefore,

$[P_x,P_y]\psi = P_xP_y\psi - P_yP_x\psi = -\hbar^2\frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial x \partial y} - -\hbar^2\frac{\partial^2  \psi}{\partial x \partial y} = 0$

Therefore,

$[P_x,P_y] = P_xP_y - P_yP_x = 0$

Note the $\psi$ wasn't used here, but I included it anyway for teaching purposes, since occasionally evaluating commutators is easier when applying them to a test function, $\psi$.

Comment: @morTie, good question.  This is a very important thing to remember because it comes up on maths and physics alot.  Basically it can be shown to be true using first principles of derivatives.  Various proofs and intuitions are provided on this question which:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170764/geometric-or-intuitive-proof-of-the-symmetry-of-second-partial-derivatives

Comment: and how does $\frac{\partial}{\partial y \partial x}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x \partial y}$ ?

Comment: @morTie, see comment above.

Comment: thanx. that helped alot.